# ConnectionAcquireTimeoutError [SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError]: Operation timeout

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I have a SQL update query that I run on a Postgres database that take a few minutes to finish.  In order to increase the output, I try to run a few instances of this query at the same time.  However, it seems like if I add anything more than 2 instances, I will end up with timeout error.  Does anyone know why this may be or how I can fix this issue?  Why does this happen when I have more than 2 instances for the update query?

This seems to only occur when it runs on Heroku and not local.